How do I train a model when train and test have different number of columns?
I am trying to predict the future movements of some objects. To do this I have a rather large set of data, which includes columns like ("time", "objectID", "direction", "speed", "rateOfTurn", "status", "latitude", "longitude", "reportedDestination") in my train data. However, the test data provided only contains ("objectID", "time", "scalingFactor").
Explanations for columns:

Time: What time the info was recorded

ObjectID: ID of the object recording the data

Direction: What direction is the object facing (0-360 degrees)

Speed: How fast is the object travelling

Rate of turn: How fast is the object changing it course 6 .Status: Objects can send out statuses such as that it is stuck, it has stopped for a while purposefully, it is working and so on.

latitude: its latitude coordinate

longitude: its longitude coordinate

reportedDestination: Name of destination for the object.

scaling factor is how much the data from this row is supposed to be weighted in the evaluation


I want to predict the future locations x amount of days in the future, but how can i do that when the test data doesn't even include latitude and longitude columns?
I have tried using both XBG and AutoGluon without any success. I have done some data-cleaning to remove invalid data instances by using the average of a forward and backward fill on places where there are missing data. I have also tried to just split the train data by having latitude and longitude in Y-train, while the rest stays in x-train. But then how do i use the model to predict the locations for the objects specified in the test data?

You can only use those features that are present in both train and test samples.
Second: ask yourself, could a human solve this task?  If not, then it might be a bit much to expect a classifier to.  To me, it seems ridiculous to imagine that one could predict the location of an object given only its ObjectID and the time.  So your entire task seems hopeless.
Before engaging machine learning "magic", think critically about whether the objective is reasonable.

Yeah, that was my thinking as well. There could be that there are some fundamentals to the task that i have misunderstood.
However, would it be possible if i used last known movements to predict future position. Something of the same nature as sliding window technique? Say I use the last 5 known positions to predict the next five for instance.

@zlatanicMachineLearner, This site is not intended for back-and-forth interaction, so it doesn't work so well for follow-up questions and extended discussion.  Instead, our goal is to serve as a repository of knowledge, in the form of questions (that others might have) and answers.  Perhaps your best bet might be to try some experiments with the ideas you have and see how well they work on your datasets.
